# Offset Android Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, android-x86, gboard, screen-resolution

I'm making an installation using Android (Bliss Os).

For getting the recognizable android keyboard that everybody knows I installed GBoard. Everything worked fine except that my keyboard misses half the most left line of letters.

Does anybody have any experience with this problem? I already tried using a different display but this didn't help.

Also tried installing *swiftkey*. But this also had the same problem. They do have a functionality to rescale the keyboard but this is a dirty fix for my problem..

[image: Picture Screen]

Sorry for the bad picture quality, I do not have the buttons on this elo touch display to take a screenshot.

Comment: Do other applications get cut off on the left side as well or is just the keyboard?

Comment: Just the keyboard

Comment: I'm not knowledge about GBoard, but is it possible there are variants for various aspect ratios?

Comment: Gboard is the standard google key board:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=nl

Comment: gboard has resize option. unfortunately only in portrait mode https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhRVq.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by disabling and re enabling the application that was forcing my device in portrait mode.

The application I was using was "Set orientation" V1.1.4 from package com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation.

Comment: Can we know which application was it that was forcing the portrait mode? How did you find it out?

Comment: @Firelord I found out by asking myself all variables that influence the display resolution. Orientation also influences this. Probably something has gone wrong with the application because you would think it would also reset at reboot (this was not the case).